# What can I use instead of overflow-anchor on Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I would like to insert elements at the top of the page without changing the visible scrolling content.

The elements are added during scrolling, when a certain percentage of the page is reached.

On Chrome everything works fine, but on Safari it does not, the visible content is pushed down and is no longer visible.

I would like to use overflow-anchor:auto to avoid this behaviour, but it is not supported by Safari, what can I use to achieve the same result?

I've already tried with requestAnimationFrame to re-align the viewport using scrollTop, but in this case it does not work as expect, because elements are added during scroll and the position keeps changing.